# The rationale for some of the ADL algorithm steps (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

In short, I am trying to understand the behavior of Argument-Dependent Lookup in C++. Some statements in ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (E) regarding ADL are not clear to me. I hope somebody would clarify them to me.

According to standard,

> ... Furthermore, if T is a class template specialization,
>   its associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters (excluding template template
>   parameters); the namespaces of which any template template arguments are members; and the classes
>   of which any member templates used as template template arguments are members.

The question is why it has to be a class template **specialization**? Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

using namespace std;                                                            

namespace N                                                                     
{                                                                               
    template <typename T>                                                       
    struct A {};                                                                

    template <typename T>                                                       
    void func (const T&) {cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;}                 
}                                                                               

template <typename T, template <typename> class S>                              
class X {};                                                                     

int main ()                                                     
{                                                                               
    typedef X<int, N::A> XX;                                                    
    func(XX{});                                                                 
}
```

As far as I can see, it compiles with both `g++` and `clang++`, and I don't have to define something like

```
template <>                                                                   
class X<int, N::A> {};
```

to make it work.

Comment: The standard uses the term "specialization" to refer to a specific instance of a template, with all parameters bound to some arguments. It is not limited to explicit or partial specialization - an implicit instantiation, say, also produces a specialization of a template. Thus, `X<int, N::A>` is a specialization of class template `X`

Comment: Re: typedefs. What the standard is saying is that `N2` is among the associated namespaces of `tfunc`, but `N` is not. In other words, `void tfunc (N::C)` works exactly the same as `void tfunc(N2::B)`. If, in your example, you move `func` to `N`, it won't be found, despite the fact that, on the surface, the declaration of `tfunc` mentions `N`.

Comment: Re: non-type parameters. It's similar to typedefs. There, the typedef name (and its associated namespaces) is not used to guide ADL - the actual type named by the typedef is. Here, similarly, the name by which an integral constant is referred to is not used to guide ADL (you might say the actual constant is - except those don't have associated namespaces so their involvement is trivial). In other words, the intent is that `func(tfunc<N::c>)` and `func(tfunc<1>)` behave the same, just as `tfunc (N::C)` and `tfunc (N2::B)` from the previous example behave the same.

Comment: Please separate your questions into three posts. Also, an HTML version of the C++17 standard is available at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/, which you can link to.

Comment: @Igor this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [[temp.spec]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#4):

> An instantiated template specialization can be either implicitly instantiated for a given argument list or be explicitly instantiated. A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized.

`X<int, N::A>` is a specialization. If you were to explicitly specialize `X` for the arguments `int` and `N::A`, it would also be a specialization. (In C++20, the term "declared specialization" was introduced to specifically refer to the latter case; [temp.inst]/1.)

So the quoted paragraph applies to an argument of type `X<int, N::A>`; the namespace `N` is an associated namespace.