# ADL and non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

ADL is not considered for non-type template parameters. What is the reason for that? My initial thought was that ADL had been introduced to resolve the collision between operators and namespaces, and operator overloads do not use non-type template parameters. I'm not sure that this is right.
So, why the following is not permitted?

```
namespace N
{
    const int c = 1;
    void func(...) {}
}

template <int r>
void tfunc () {}

int main ()
{
    func(tfunc<N::c>);  // Error!
}
```

What I am looking for is an example that demonstrates why this is a bad idea.

Comment: As you point out in your self-answer, the answer is actually in [The rationale for some of the ADL algorithm steps (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236904/the-rationale-for-some-of-the-adl-algorithm-steps-c), so this is a duplicate.  **Later:** OK, I see that was just in a comment now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is provided by @IgorTandetnik.

It's similar to typedefs. There, the typedef name (and its associated namespaces) is not used to guide ADL - the actual type named by the typedef is. Here, similarly, the name by which an integral constant is referred to is not used to guide ADL (you might say the actual constant is - except those don't have associated namespaces so their involvement is trivial). In other words, the intent is that `func(tfunc<N::c>)` and `func(tfunc<1>)` behave the same.

Comment: Where was this answer by Igor provided?

Comment: @MaxLanghof https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236904/the-rationale-for-some-of-the-adl-algorithm-steps-c I've been asked to split the original question into three posts.